# Is the infinitive form of the verb appropriate in this sentence?

Tags: verbs

I came across the following and would like to find out whether the bolded part is properly formed:

> To be honest it sounds like she’s got the perfect relationship, in her eyes, going right now.  So I don’t think you should **be swayed when she desires keep having it.**

Should it be "keep" or "to keep"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between these options, you should definitely choose the infinitive here:

> To be honest it sounds like she’s got the perfect relationship, in her eyes, going right now. So I don’t think you should be swayed when she desires **to keep** having it.

However, the entire sentence could be improved (and I could do better if I had context):

> To be honest, it sounds like she thinks she’s got the perfect relationship going right now. So I don’t think you should be surprised if she says she wants it to continue.

(I'm not sure if you wanted the word "swayed" in there; correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: +1 for what looks like good reasoning re *swayed*. But if you wanted to reduce the "informal" tone a bit, *wants it to continue* might be better.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't sure myself of the last part there, and I like your suggestion better.

Answer (score 2):

The verb *desire* takes the infinitive form, so *I desire to eat* is correct and *I desire eat* is not. However, the gerund of the verb can be used as normal noun, so *I desire eating* would also be appropriate.

So in regards to the original question, these forms would be appropriate (although the second one changes the meaning a little):

> So I don't think you should be swayed when she desires to keep having it.
>
> So I don't think you should be swayed when she desires having it.

As @drm65 has noted, the entire sentence could be improved to make it more concise and clear, with something like this:

> So I don't think you should be surprised if she says she wants to continue it.

But be aware that the same issue with the infinitive is present in this form. *If she says she wants to continue it* is correct, but *if she says she wants continue it* is not correct.