# Difference between "to think" and "think"

Tags: meaning

Kate: I love to read.Really! But I don't read because I want people to think I'm smart.I can't stand those pompous people who try to show off how much they know about literature.

Why in the above context there is " I want people to think " instead of  " I want people think"

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: Because that is how _want_ works. I'm sorry, but that is the **whole** of the answer: there is no other explanation than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the infinitive form of the verb appropriate in this sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/35275/26083) See also [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/329/26083)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, some verbs are followed by the **infinitive with "to"** (the full infinitive)

- want - "I want to go", "I want you to stay"
- promise - "He promised to do it"
- and there is a long list of such verbs (forget, agree, manage, decide, love, hate, watch, bid,  etc)

Some verbs are followed by the **infinitive without "to"** (the bare infinitive)

- let - "let me help you"
- make (except in the passive voice) - "she made me do it"
- dare - "I dare not wake him", "I don't dare (to) wake him"
- need (except when conjugated with do/will/would) "You need not say anything about it"
- etc, etc.

Other verbs can be followed by **infinitive with or without "to"**

- help - "John helped me (to) push the car"

In your example, "want" is one of those verbs that can be followed by object + infinitive, just like tell, order, allow, encourage, request, forbid, warn, teach, etc) and **in this case the infinitive has to be preceded by "to" (the full infinitive)**  This is just a summary.  For more on the subject, [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/infinitives-with-and-without-to) and [Edufind](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/infinitive/) and [the OPG](http://pt.slideshare.net/muhammadusafari/oxford-practice-grammar-with-answers-27003280)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the infinitive **to think** is a [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)) of the verb **want**.

In other words, "I want people to think" is grammatically correct, but "I want people think" is not.

Recommended reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive#Uses_of_the_infinitive